# Why doesn't TeKaMoLo rule work here?

Tags: sentence-structure

According to the TeKaMoLo "rule" the following phrase should be organized like this:

> Heute habe ich einen Termin wegen meiner Scheidung mit meinem
> Rechtsanwalt im Büro.

But if you try to write this in DeepL, the AI gives you the following order:

> Heute habe ich einen Termin mit meinem Rechtsanwalt im Büro wegen
> meiner Scheidung.

This is a temporal-modal-lokal-kausal order.

Does this happen because "einen Termin" is closely related to "mit meinem Rechtsanwalt" and they work better together in this case and the connection between "Scheidung" and "im Büro" makes it seem that the divorce will happen in the office?

Or because something else?

Comment: This is not a rule. The are very few rules regarding word order in German (e.g., V2). Word order is mostly about what you want to emphasize. Both of your examples are correct grammar but the DeepL translation feels more natural. I'm pretty sure your question is a duplicate.

Comment: For deciding word order questions in German, you always need context, in order to decide what is new information, what is emphasised, and what is given. -- "Tekamolo" is no use: it posits an ordering in terms of different adverbial classes, but each of them would have subclasses that behave differently wrt word order.

Comment: Was ist TeKaMoLo? Klingt wie eine mexikanische Gottheit. :) Time, K?, Motiv, Location?

Answer (score 7):

There are 240 different grammatically correct permutations of this sentence. Namely, the two you mentioned in your question and 238 other correct permutations.<sup>1</sup>

In German, the identification of constituents depends not so much on the order of words, but much more on grammatical features than in many other languages, such as English. Yes, there are rules for word order in German, but they are much less strict than in English.

These are strict rules for complete sentences that are statements:

- The inflected verb must be in position 2.
- All other verbs must be at the very end of the sentence, including split-off former prefixes of separable verbs whose main part is in position 2.
- The subject stands at position 1 or position 3.
- All other parts of the sentence may be placed more or less anywhere.

The rules you are talking about are recommendations for commonly used orders for *"all other parts of the sentence".* These rules are very weak. Most native German speakers have never heard of them. Ask German native speakers about the TeKaMoLo rule, and at least 19 out of 20 will have no idea what you're talking about. I estimate that these rules are broken in more than 50% of all sentences, because German native speakers don't care about them. (This makes it hard for us to realize the importance of correct word order in other languages when we learn them as foreign language.)

What matters much more in German is the emphasis you want to place on certain parts of the sentence. In spoken language, you can do this by putting more emphasis on some words or by inserting short pauses before important words. But another very common way, which also works in written texts, is to change the order of words.

Here are some randomly chosen examples of the same sentence with other word orders, that all can be absolutely fine in certain situations:

> Im Büro habe ich mit meinem Rechtsanwalt heute wegen meiner Scheidung einen Termin.
> Einen Termin habe ich heute im Büro mit meinem Rechtsanwalt wegen meiner Scheidung.
> Wegen meiner Scheidung habe ich mit meinem Rechtsanwalt im Büro einen Termin heute.
> Mit meinem Rechtsanwalt habe ich einen Termin wegen meiner Scheidung im Büro heute.
> Ich habe heute im Büro wegen meiner Scheidung mit meinem Rechtsanwalt einen Termin.
> Mit meinem Rechtsanwalt habe ich heute einen Termin im Büro wegen meiner Scheidung.
> Einen Termin habe ich mit meinem Rechtsanwalt heute im Büro wegen meiner Scheidung.
> Mit meinem Rechtsanwalt habe ich im Büro einen Termin wegen meiner Scheidung heute.
> Ich habe im Büro heute wegen meiner Scheidung mit meinem Rechtsanwalt einen Termin.
> Ich habe einen Termin heute mit meinem Rechtsanwalt wegen meiner Scheidung im Büro.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This sentence has 7 parts. The verb must be in position 2, so there is only 1 position for the verb. The subject can be in position 1 or 3, so there are 2 possible positions for the subject. There are 5 positions left for the 5 other parts of the sentence. There are 5∙4∙3∙2∙1=120 possible permutations of 5 elements in 5 positions. So, in total we have 1∙2∙120=240 different sequences.</sub>

Comment: It's interesting that AI picked an order other than the default. It's assuming "new information" here is "wegen meiner Scheidung", which seems reasonable even to we mere humans. The reason the TeKaMoLo rule is taught to learners is that produces a word order that isn't wrong or odd sounding, even if does miss the subtleties of emphasis that word order conveys to the practiced ear. In particular, English tends to put time adverbs last instead of first, and I suppose TeKaMoLo helps to break that habit in learners.

Answer (score 4):

A problem with your example is that you would already doubt how to divide it into major constituents. It is possible that we are not dealing with an ordering problem for adverbials but with one big nominal group:

- *Einen Termin mit meinem Rechtsanwalt wegen meiner Scheidung* habe ich erst morgen.

On the other hand, it is possible to take "einen Termin haben" as a compound predicate, and what looks like modifiers of "Termin" are in fact treated as adverbials at clause level. But this uncertainty might influence word order.

Incidentally, I find it difficult to come up with a fully satisfying ordering for your example; there is somehow too much stuff and for stylistic reasons I would simply omit "im Büro" because it is unclear anyway, it doesn't make clear whose office it is (and so you don't know how close it should be to "Rechtsanwalt" etc)...

All this already creates problems, apart from the fact that you don't know whether the grouping should be *[einen Termin im Büro] haben* ("einen Bürotermin") or rather *im Büro [einen Termin haben]*.